# When we talk about 'a closure' do we refer to a single variable, or do we refer to all 'closed' variables?

Tags: terminology, closures

Let's take the following (JavaScript) code that returns a function that closes over variables `x` and `y` to illustrate:

```
function test() {
  var x = Math.random();
  var y = Math.random();
  var f = function() { 
    console.log(x, y); 
  };

  return f;
}
test()();
```

*The code is nonsensical, I just want to close over `x` and `y`.*

Variables `x` and `y` don't exist outside of the function `test` but they remain available in the function `f`.

Barring any compiler optimizations (like inlining), do we say there is a single closure (*created by* `f`), or do we say there are two closures (*for/over* `x` and `y`)?

Comment: `single` is the correct answer.

Comment: From the [Closure article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) (emphasis mine): "a closure [...] is a *function* together with a referencing environment for the non-local variables of that function". To answer your question: it's a single closure created by `f`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"A closure" is a function that closes over one or more variables, not the variable(s) that are closed over.  So it's a single closure.

Answer (score 3):

A closure is a first class function that captures the lexical bindings of variables defined in it's environment.  When it captures the bindings it is said to have *"closed over"* the variables.

Note: this means *closures only exist at runtime* (once it has *"closed over"* variables).

So in the example above a single closure is created when the code is executed.  This closure is *"closed over"* the variables `x` and `y`.